# Does the julia round function contain an error for large numbers?

Tags: julia, precision, biginteger, digits, arbitrary-precision

The julia round function seems to work OK up to factorial(75), but breaks at factorial 76.  Is this a bug in the round function?

```
julia>round(factorial(big(75)), sigdigits=2)
2.5e+109

julia>round(factorial(big(76)), sigdigits=2)
1.900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006e+111
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to increase the precision of `BigFloat` compuations to get the right result e.g. like this:

```
julia> setprecision(1000) do
       round(factorial(big(76)), sigdigits=2)
       end
1.9e+111
```

The source of the problem is that when rounding Julia represents `{base}^{number of digits to round}` as an appropriate float. In this case it is `BigFloat(10)^-110` which under default precision is not precise enough for the required number of digits.

Comment: That was a great answer and exactly explained my problem.